# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unitService' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this class in TypeScript and when I call `this.unitService` I get an error.

controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import Unit from "../models/unit.model";
import Relation from "../models/relation.model";
import { TypeRelation } from "../models/typeralation.enum";
import { UnitService } from "../services/unit.service";

export class HomeController {
  unitService: UnitService = new UnitService();
  constructor() { }

  forceCreateUnit(req: Request, res: Response): void {
    const unit = "{ type: " + TypeRelation.USE + ", topUnit: new ObjectId(\"5adf231d85dded040f3f6d03\"), lowerUnit: new ObjectId(\"5adf231d85dded040f3f6d03\")}";
    this.unitService.prueba();
    res.send("OK");
  }
}
```

unit.service.ts

```js
import Relation from "../models/relation.model";
import { TypeRelation } from "../models/typeralation.enum";
import { ObjectId } from "bson";

export class UnitService {
    constructor() {}
    async forceGenerate(unit: String) {
        const relation = new Relation(
            {
              type: TypeRelation.USE,
              topUnit: new ObjectId("5adf231d85dded040f3f6d03"),
              lowerUnit: new ObjectId("5adf231d85dded040f3f6d03")
            }
          );
          await relation.save();
    }
}
```

However when I put `new unitService()` in `forceCreateUnit()`, it works good. Why is that?

I call method like this:

```
const homeController: HomeController = new HomeController();

homeRoutes.get("/prueba", homeController.forceCreateUnit);
```

Comment: your import should be import { UnitService } from "../services/unitservice";  or change file name unit.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'unitService' of undefined
>
> I have this class in TypeScript and when I call `this.unitService` I get an error.

`this` is therefore `undefined`. The issue comes from the way you call `forceCreateUnit`.

Try that:

```
homeRoutes.get("/prueba", (req, res) => homeController.forceCreateUnit(req, res));
```